# how to execute a function in a file in pymodule

Tags: rust

This is an official py03 example.

```rust
Python::with_gil(|py| -> PyResult<Py<PyAny>> {
    let py_app = include_str!(concat!(env!("CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR"), "/app.py"));
    let app: Py<PyAny> = PyModule::from_code(py, py_app, "", "")?
        .getattr("test_function")?
        .into();
    app.call0(py)
})
```

my local app.py contains the following where the import is the rust module:

```py
import GQLwrapper
    
print("running app.py")
def test_function:
    print("running test function")
```

The rust call is running the file and 'running app.py' is printed but the test function itself is not being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `call_method0` on the module.

```
use pyo3::prelude::*;

fn main() -> pyo3::PyResult<()> {
    const CODE: &str = r#"
print("running app.py")

def test_function():
   print("running test function")

"#;

    Python::with_gil(|py| {
        let module = PyModule::from_code(py, CODE, "", "")?;
        let result = module.call_method0("test_function")?;
        Ok(())
    })
}
```